# Chrome crashes when trying to modify CSS3 animation from Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, css, css-animations

I have an HTML file with this:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

and I have a stylesheet with a CSS3 animation defined:

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-name: image-create;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes image-create {
    from {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
    }
    to {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
}
```

This should make an image grow from 0x0 to 500x500.
In my Javascript file I have the following:

```
var findAnimation = function(name) {
    for (var i in document.styleSheets) {
        var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
        for (var j in styleSheet.cssRules) {
            var rule = styleSheet.cssRules[j];
            if (rule.type === 7 && rule.name == name) {
                return rule;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var addImage = function(x, y, src) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    image.className = "image";
    image.style.width = "500px";
    image.style.height = "500px";
    image.style.left = x;
    image.style.top = y;
    image.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(image);
        var animation = findAnimation("image-create");
        for (var i in animation.cssRules) {
            var rule = animation.cssRules[i];
            if (rule.keyText == "0%") {
                rule.style.top = y;
                rule.style.left = x;
            }
            if (rule.keyText == "100%") {
                rule.style.top = 0;
                rule.style.left = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

addImage(100, 100, "http://i.imgur.com/KGfgH.jpg");
```

​

When addImage() is called, I'm trying to create an image at the coordinates (x, y). The animation should make it grow while also move from the location where the image was created (x, y) to the top left corner (0, 0).

Instead, Chrome just crashes to the "Aw, snap" page. Does anyone know why this is the case?

EDIT: Here is an example. This crashes for me if I visit it: http://jsfiddle.net/LVpWS/10/

In this one I commented out some lines and it does not crash: http://jsfiddle.net/LVpWS/21/

EDIT2: It works if I switch back to Chrome 20.

Comment: Which Chrome version? Crashing in what way? "Aw, snap", non-responsive, or a full application failure?

Comment: Chrome 21.0.1180.57 beta, the crash is the kind where the contents of the tab are replaced by a blue screen with a sad face on it.

Comment: That's the "Aw, snap" page (viewable through `chrome://crash`). Have you tried to debug the page yourself by watching the memory usage and/or setting breakpoints and/or commenting out some code?

Comment: Yes, http://jsfiddle.net/LVpWS/21/ this one does not crash for me, after commenting out rule.style.top = and rule.style.left =. Do you know what is wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Narrowed the error down to: http://jsfiddle.net/LVpWS/68/. Setting a property which wasn't specified in the rule is causing this error, which is proved by the fact that this does not crash: http://jsfiddle.net/LVpWS/69/. I've submitted a crash report (Tools->Report an issue) with this message: http://pastebin.com/t7HY4REQ.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to include the properties I want to change in the rule. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I've isolated the error:
The page crashes (Aw, snap) when a new property is added to a `WebKitCSSKeyframeRule` instance.
The bug can be reproduced in Chrome 21.0.1180.57 using the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/LVpWS/68/

```
<style id="sheet">
@-webkit-keyframes test {
    from {}
}</style><script>
var keyFramesRule = document.getElementById('sheet').sheet.cssRules[0];
var keyFrameRule = keyFramesRule[0];
keyFrameRule.style.top = 0;</script>
```

This crash does not happen when the property already exists in the rule. Replace `from {}` with `from{top:1px;}` to check that: http://jsfiddle.net/LVpWS/69/.

Comment: I've already sent a crash report using `Tools->Report an issue`. I can't [find it in the bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=WebKitCSSKeyframeRule) though.

Comment: FYI: This bug does not occur in Chrome 22.0.1229.79 any more.